# why can't install the xdebug?

Tags: php, xdebug

my op system is `XP`. the PHP Version `5.3.6`. the php path is `D:/php`

i downloaded the  `PHP 5.3 VC6 (32 bit`) version from the http://www.xdebug.org/download.php

i added the following code to the `php.ini`:

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension="D:/php/ext/php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.collect_params=On
xdebug.collect_return=On
xdebug.trace_output_dir="d:\xdebug" 
xdebug.profiler_enable=On 
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="d:\xdebug"
```

then restarted the apache, using `phpinfo()`. it doesn't output the xdebug. what's wrong with my setting? thank you.

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) Check out the Apache error log. Is there any error visible? 2) On my old XP I've misplaced the `php.ini` a few times myself and edited the wrong one. Are you sure you've edited the one your PHP installation grabs while loading?

Answer (score 0):

Download http://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc6-nts.dll

rename it `php_xdebug.dll`

Put it in `D:/php/ext/`

Restart apache

Comment: @enjoylife
is your problem solved??
i have the same issue? What to do?